# Finding a file path in c

Tags: objective-c, c, ios

I'm working on an iOS project and need to supply a file path for a sqlite call in a c function.  I know for objective-c calls, you can use a function like this one to get the path:

```
+ (NSString *) FilePath:(NSString *) fileName {
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
}
```

I can't use this function in my c as it has to remain as-is (no obj-c). Is there a similar type of call in c, or is there a build setting in xcode4 to help put the code access the database file correctly? I've been banging my head against this and would appreciate any assistance!
7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once you get your NSString, call [`-UTF8String`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/UTF8String) or [`-cStringUsingEncoding:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/cStringUsingEncoding%3a) on it to get your C string able to be passed to your sqlite function.

Comment: Excellent - thanks! Out of curiosity, there's no native support in c to lookup the file path?

Comment: No. Objective-C itself also has no support. It's all done via Foundation, which includes this convenience. In C, you'd have to use an external library probably, I just don't remember some to recommend you.

Comment: I wasn't sure if I was missing it somewhere - this gives me a solid direction. Thanks again!